# Strange behavior of mdframed with pstricks as framemethod

Tags: pstricks, mdframed, shadows

I load the `mdframed` package from a class of my own with the line

```
\RequirePackage[framemethod=pstricks]{mdframed}
```

When using the `XeLaTeX` engine I get a strange behavior from the `mdframed` environment defined as

```
\newmdenv[%
   skipabove=\baselineskip, 
   skipbelow=\baselineskip,
   leftmargin=0pt,
   rightmargin=0pt,
   linecolor=black,
   shadow=false,
   backgroundcolor=white,
   pstrickssetting={shadow=true,blur=true,
   shadowsize=2pt,shadowcolor=darkgray}
]{remarksbox}
```

The strange behavior appears when the frame is split across two pages, in which case I get a solid shadow as opposed to the blurred form I am defining for the environment. When there is no frame splitting, it works just right and I get a fading shadow.

The following lines can be considered as providing an MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor,pstricks,pst-blur,lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=pstricks]{mdframed}

\newmdenv[skipabove=\baselineskip,
skipbelow=\baselineskip,
leftmargin=0pt,
rightmargin=0pt,
linecolor=black,
shadow=false,
outerlinewidth=0pt,%0.4pt,
frametitle=Remarks,
frametitlefont=\normalfont\normalsize,
frametitlerule=false,
backgroundcolor=white,
pstrickssetting={shadow=true,blur=true,
shadowsize=3pt,shadowcolor=gray}]{remarksbox}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{remarksbox}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{remarksbox}
\lipsum[5-10]
\begin{remarksbox}
\lipsum[11-15]
\end{remarksbox}
\end{document}
```

Can anybody replicate this behavior with the environment I've just defined? Besides, the shadow under the environment's title looks awful. How can it be suppressed?

Comment: Could you turn your snippet into a complete MWE that exhibits the behaviour? :)

Comment: As @cmhughes mentioned without a complete MWE we can't help you. To  provided example text you can use packages like `kantlipsum`, `lipsum` `blindtext`.

Comment: I have appended an MWE. Sorry about the delay and thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that looks like an internal bug in the parameter setting. However, do not define `shadow` inside the PSTricks setting then it will work:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{pstricks,pst-blur,lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=pstricks]{mdframed}

\newmdenv[skipabove=\baselineskip,
skipbelow=\baselineskip,
leftmargin=0pt,
rightmargin=0pt,
shadow=true,%%  this is ok!
outerlinewidth=0pt,%0.4pt,
frametitle=Remarks,
frametitlefont=\normalfont\normalsize,
frametitlerule=false,
backgroundcolor=white,
pstrickssetting={blur,shadowsize=3pt,shadowcolor=gray% no shadow=true!
}]{remarksbox}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{remarksbox}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{remarksbox}
\lipsum[5-10]
\begin{remarksbox}
\lipsum[11-15]
\end{remarksbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[...]

[image]